# Trim blank data/rows, rename column headers based on sheet names, move data from one sheet to another.

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is what I want to do in Microsoft Excel 2010:

I have several spreadsheets with data in them, and the spreadsheets have the data in multiple sheets (the tabs at the bottom) but they are all in the same column/format. However, the columns may have an extra row or two above them that may have text or may be blank, so I would have to trim that off.

I want to copy the data into a master spreadsheet. In the master spreadsheet, the columns are named after the sheets so, in order to automate this, I would have to compare the name of the sheet that was copied from against the text in the columns (they will always be in the first row).

Is it even possible to move data between different Excel files with a macro?

Answer (score 5):

You can do that without macros using [Consolidation](http://www.google.com/search?q=excel%202010%20data%20consolidation). If you're a beginner, I suggest you start trying to solve the problem with existing solutions, before going to macros...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is all possible. Anything you can do manually in Excel you can generally also do through VBA.

If you know nothing at all about Excel VBA programming, then a good place to start is at one of [these sites](http://www.mvps.org/links.html#Excel). I would particularly recommend Chip Pearson's body of work [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx).